# Regex to validate words do not contain numbers or special characters

Tags: java, regex

I am developing a java app, running on android.  I am trying to pick all words which do not contain any embedded digits or symbols.

The best I have come up with is:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]*+\b
```

Test Data:

```
this is a test , an0ther gr8 WW##ee one, w1n 1test test1 end
```

This results in picking the following: `this, is, a, test, WW##ee, one, end`

I need to eliminate the `WW##ee` from the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution has evolved a bit as I have gotten additional help with this.  So, this is now my best solution but still a bit lacking.  I have not been able to accept "as-is" while rejecting "-this-" and a similar case of accept "and/or" while rejecting "/slash/".  Also for simplicity I have made the input data single word per line.

^(?:[\p{P}\p{S}])*?((?:[\p{L}\p{Pd}'])+)(?:[\p{P}\p{S}])*$

as-is is picked valid

-this- is valid but I wish it weren't

and/or is not valid but I wish it would be picked

/slash/ "slash" is picked valid

(test) "test" is picked valid

[test] "test" is picked valid

<test> "test" is picked valid

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a word boundary meta-character `\b` since it matches the position right after `WW` which sees a hash `#` character. This position is a word boundary itself. So you should pick up a different way:

```
(?<![\S&&[^,]])[a-zA-Z]+(?![\S&&[^,]])
```

Using character class intersection feature of Java's regex you are able to define punctuation characters that are allowed to follow or precede a word character. Here it is a comma `,`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use look behind and look ahead to check there is no `#`.

```
\b(?<!\#)[a-zA-Z]+(?!\#)\b
```